# To play .wav files using Python from within Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I need to play .wav files stored on my PC using Python script from Cygwin.

Please advice if this is possible? If so please provide pointers etc, to Python script code which can be used from Cygwin. I am working on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

This is what I have done so far.

- Downloaded and installed setup-x86_64.exe from cygwin website.
- Installed packages as part of Cygwin:  `make,gcc,g++,git,ssh,sox,python ver >= 2.7, curl,wget`.

Please advice on how to play .wav files using Python (version >= 2.7) from Cygwin.

Comment: I think you'd be better off finding a command-line utility that will play .wav files (see e.g. [this question on Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/276596/play-mp3-or-wav-file-via-linux-command-line)) and then invoking it from Python using `subprocess`.

Comment: Thanks Senshin. So I will use Sox since it is a command line utility. (But to use Sox from within Cygwin, 'playaudio' package has also to be downloaded.)

Answer (score 3):

try os.system("cat /path/foo.wav > /dev/dsp")

You need to install audio package for Cygwin first.

Comment: Please tell us how that "audio package for Cygwin" is called!